# Best practices for JSON responses on a MS-SQL and NODE architecture

Tags: sql-server, json, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

GoodDay, starting experimentation on Node against MsSql on Azure for solutions very data-centric.

**What would be best practice for this short of architecture ?** 
(all communication to the DB to be made trough Store Procedures, obviously)

So far, we are experimenting with https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql and found that output parameters last a while sometimes until they become ready...

so we have thought into:

- SP call parameters as separate input-Parameters (easier to treat in SQL)
- Data to node application as a single (sometimes composed) JSON, as a recordset
- SP execution code trough RETURN (202 ok, rest of codes as w3c web codes)
- Return message, in case of error, trough an output parameter.

**Any indications ?**

I found very interesting this binomia (Node + MsSQL), strength from one side, flexibility and speed from the other one ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to return single JSON object as recordset, are you planning to just execute select query with FOR JSON clause? MSSQL [supports JSON outputs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#json-support), but even without this feature maybe you can use [pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#pipe-stream) method to stream results into output stream (I have not tried it).
Here is a sample app that uses tedious and just stream FOR JSON output to Http response output:
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/json/todo-app/nodejs-express4-rest-api/routes/todo.js and just stream results generated by FOR JSON to Http output. It does not uses MSSQL but you can easily rewrite it to use MSSQL.

FOR JSON might be handy if you want to return chunked data to clients since Azure SQL Database spits large JSON responses into 2KB chunks, but MSSQL enables you to parse entire response as one big object.

Regarding error handling, it might be a little bit unusual to return HTTP error codes directly from stored proc as output paramters. Maybe you can use standard throw/raiserror statements and map error code to Http error codes. There are around 80 useful Http error codes in the 4xx and 5xx range so even error state (tinyint) would be enough.